# Deserialize interface in request body based on specific condition asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm making a small web application using `ASP.Net Core 2.2`.

Currently I am having one interface:

```
public interface ILocation {

    public int Type {get;}
}
```

There are 2 classes implement this `ILocation` interface:

```
public class StreetLocation: ILocation {

    public int Type {get;set;}

    public string City {get;set;}

    public string State {get;set;}
}

public class GeoCoordinateLocation: ILocation {

    public int Type {get;set;}

    public double Latitude{get;set;}

    public double Longitude{get;set;}
}
```

I have one class `StudentViewModel` which is for receiving information that is sent from client to server. This class is implemented as below:

```
public class StudentViewModel {

    public Guid Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public ILocation Address {get;set;}
}
```

My request sent from client will be like this:

```
{
    "id": "0da28089-c0da-41a7-a47f-89b54d52822b",
    "name": "Student 01",
    "location": {
        "type": 1,
        ...
    }
}
```

If the **location type** is 1, `ILocation` will be deserialize as `StreetLocation`, and as `GeoCoordinateLocation` if **location type** is 2.

Are there any solutions about this please ?
Could it be done by `IModelBinder` in asp.net core ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom `JsonConverter` to do that.

1. create a helper function to resolve the location type during runtime :`Type ResolveILocationTypeRuntime(typeCode)`
2. create a helper function to create an instance of some specific type during runtime : `DeserializeLocationRuntime(json, type)`
3. Read Json or Write Json according to current `type`.

**Implementation:**

```
public class CustomLocationConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var json= JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        var typeToken = json.SelectToken("type"); // or ??json.SelectToken("Type");
        if(typeToken ==null) return null;         //  
        var type= ResolveILocationTypeRuntime((int)typeToken);
        var location = DeserializeLocationRuntime(json, type);
        return location;
    }

    private Type ResolveILocationTypeRuntime(int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1:
                return typeof(StreetLocation);
            case 2:
                return typeof(GeoCoordinateLocation);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("type should be 1|2");
        }
    }
    private ILocation DeserializeLocationRuntime(JToken json, Type locationType)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(JToken)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(m => m.Name == "ToObject" && m.GetParameters().Length == 0 && m.IsGenericMethod)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            ?.MakeGenericMethod(locationType);
        var location = mi?.Invoke(json, null);
        return (ILocation)location;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var location = value as ILocation;
        var type = ResolveILocationTypeRuntime(location.Type);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, location, type );
    }
}
```

And decorate your `Address` property with a `JsonConverterAttribute`:

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomLocationConverter))]

    public ILocation Address { get; set; }
}
```

### Test Case:

**controller action** :

```
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]StudentViewModel model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

**request:**

```
POST https://localhost:5001/home/test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": "0da28089-c0da-41a7-a47f-89b54d52822b",
    "name": "Student 01",
    "location": {
        "type":2,
        "latitude": 1.2,
        "longitude":3.1415926,
    }
}
```

[image: demo]